# How to move a svg graphic across canvas using createjs and animate cc

Tags: javascript, svg, html5-canvas, createjs, animate-cc

Hello I am new to javascript and createjs.
I am trying to create an animation where I have a firework that moves up to the sky and explodes. I have my firework on screen and have turned it into a movie clip. I gave it an instance name (red_firework). Now I am trying to make it move up so I went to the library to find the code that does makes it move across a path. So now my code looks like this:

```
createjs.MotionGuidePlugin.install();
createjs.Tween.get(this.red_firework).to({guide:{ path:[0,0, 0,200,200,200, 200,0,0,0] }},7000);   
graphics.moveTo(0,0);
```

This makes my firework start at 0,0, move around a bit, then and end at 0,0. I do not understand how to make it move in a straight line. I tried changing the numbers but it ends up not working.

Any help and advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
createjs.Tween.get(this.red_firework, { loop: true })
  .to({ y: 100 }, 1000, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(2));
```

Ended up finding this instead, works great